# Braintree swap method fails to update new columns

Tags: php, laravel-5, braintree

So I have just started getting familiar with [Braintree](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-braintree) with Laravel and it seems to be a pretty good package to handle payments and subscriptions. But I have encountered a little problem.

When a user is subscribing, with a "card", and want to change plan and continue with a PayPal solution, the "special" PayPal email seems not to be updated in the `users` table.

This is my current `create` method.

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // Does the plan exist?
        $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->plan);

        // Check the integrity of the form "value"
        if($request->user()->subscribedToPlan($plan->braintree_plan, 'main')){
            return redirect()->route('account.index')->with('error', 'You already have a subscription to this plan!');
        }

        if(!$request->user()->subscribed('main')) {
            // Add the new subscription record to the database
            $request->user()->newSubscription('main', $plan->braintree_plan)->create($request->payment_method_nonce);
        }else{
            // If user already is subscibed, then swap current plan to another choosen plan
            $request->user()->subscription('main')->swap($plan->braintree_plan);
        }

        // If everything went okey, redirect to account.index with flash message!
        return redirect()->route('account.index')->with('success', 'You have successfully subscribed!');
    }
```

The extra columns on `users` migrations are these ([see larval docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#configuration))

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('braintree_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('paypal_email')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
    });
```

When signing up for a fresh subscription with card, `braintree_id`, `card_brand` and `card_last_four` is updated on the users row. Everything is fine. But when the users change payment method, to PayPal, `PayPal_email` is **not** updated with the users PayPal email.

The same goes for if the users starts a fresh subscription with PayPal, and then later change to card; `card_brand` and `card_last_four` is **not** updated.

How can I populate the columns, when changing payment method?

Comment: Please expand on and clarify your question. It's unclear, at least to me, what problem you're facing.

Comment: @Shea Hope my edit explains the problem